# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional AFTER conditional unwrap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, twitter, option-type

I am using XCode 7.0 and am taking the iTunesU course, Stanford CS193p. The program, "Smashtag," is meant to display tweets related to a search. I have tried to add on my own, a feature to tap a tweet and it will display it in a different view controller. The tableviewcell class has a variable:

```
    var tweet: Tweet?
```

The tweet class has a user, which contains the screen name and name, as well as the url for their profile image which is an optional. In my table view controller, I have created a segue after clicking on a cell:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController{
        if let identifier = segue.identifier{
            if identifier == "showTweet"{
                if let selectedTweet = sender as? TweetTableViewCell{
                    vc.tweetToDisplay = selectedTweet.tweet!
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my other view controller, I have in a different thread:

```
self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
self.tweetMedia.image = UIImage(data: mediaData)
self.userName.text = "\(tweetToDisplay.user.name)"
self.userScreenName.text = "\(tweetToDisplay.user.screenName)"
if let body = tweetToDisplay.text{
    self.tweetBody.text = body
}
```

The userName, userScreenName, profileImage, and tweetMedia all load onto the view controller; however, The tweetBody gives the error in the title and crashes the program. I have tried optional chaining with the tweetBody; however, then the tweetBody doesn't display. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The real question seems to be why `selectedTweet.tweet` is nil.  How is that value supposed to be filled in?

Comment: are you sure that `tweetBody` itself is instantiated properly?

Comment: What is `tweetBody`? And where are you accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this issue for a few hours. What worked for me was storing the data exchange between view controllers in separate variables. Below is the solution that worked for me.. Hope that helps.

Instead of -

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController{
        if let identifier = segue.identifier{
            if identifier == "showTweet"{
                if let selectedTweet = sender as? TweetTableViewCell{
                    vc.tweetToDisplay = selectedTweet.tweet!
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

try -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController{
            if let identifier = segue.identifier{
                if identifier == "showTweet"{
                    if let selectedTweet = sender as? TweetTableViewCell{
                    guard let tweetText = selectedTweet.tweet! else {
                     return
                    }    
                    vc.tweetToDisplayText = tweetText
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In your other View Controller declare a string variable -

```
var tweetToDisplayText:String?
```

and finally in the `viewDidLoad:` method add-

```
tweetToDisplay.text = tweetToDisplayText
```

Answer (score -1):

Its Too simple my friend just replace  these two lines

```
(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) to (segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
```

and

```
let selectedTweet = sender as? TweetTableViewCell to let selectedTweet = sender as TweetTableViewCell
```

this will work fine.Happy coding.Provide your feedback.